# How to exclude query params not defined as model attributes from filter criteria

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I'm using sails with the Blueprint API for the RESTful handling an am having an issue with a simple GET request. Take the following model for example. We'll call it `Project`:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        id: {
            type: 'string',
            unique: true
        },

        name: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        displayName: {
            type: 'string'
        },

        ...
};
```

Since I have a `ProjectController.js` defined, Blueprint sets up a route for me at `GET /project`. If I make a request to this URL, I get all of the unfiltered results for this model, which is correct. There are also other params such as `limit`, `sort`, etc that can be used such as `GET /project?limit=5` and I still get all of my results (assuming I don't have more than 5).

The problem lies when I provide a query param that isn't reserved for the API such as `limit`. Now, it uses this param as a filter criteria (`GET /project?foo`) and I get no results back.

My models are setup with `sails.config.models.schema = true` so that only fields defined in `attributes` will be populated as I do not want junk information stored. Seeing as how I've specified for the model to follow the schema, I would ideally like it to also ignore filter criteria that is not defined as an attribute. Essentially, `GET /project?foo` should return all results since `foo` isn't a valid attribute.

The main reason for this is there is a cache buster param sent with each request and Sails is interpreting it as a filter param thus skewing my results.

Thoughts?

Comment: do you need to be generic or can be model specify

Answer (score 0):

In response to M U's follow-up comment, the idea here would be something that's generic and not specific to a model or controller. I looked into the idea of using policies, but then I would need to define that policy to be used on each controller which still wouldn't allow for a more specific filtering of params on a case-by-case basis.

The end goal here was to not have to define any methods in my controller since Blueprints implicitly handles them (eg. `GET project/` would use Blueprints `find()` method automatically. Unfortunately I wasn't able completely get away with not having to define my own `ProjectController.find()` method, but it seems pretty reasonable since I can still call Blueprints middleware in a single line.

Here's an example utility module for stripping out params from the different scopes of the request (`query`, `body` and `params`). The comments hopefully speak for themselves:

**requestUtils.js**

```
var _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = {
    sanitizeRequestParams: function (req, scope, opts) {
        var scopes = ['query', 'body', 'params'],

            // global params to strip, keep and convert. Additional configurations can be supplied
            // in the `opts` argument
            stripParams = ['_dc'],
            keepParams = [],
            convertParams = {

                /**
                 * Convert the `page` param into a calculated `skip` param for ORM
                 *
                 * The client-side framework will include the following for model
                 * requests:
                 *      ?_dc=XXX&limit=XX&page=XX&start=XX
                 *
                 * The only one ORM will not use for filter criteria is `limit`. So
                 * instead of using `page`, we will calculate the number of records
                 * to skip from the `page` and `limit` params and set that to the
                 * request instead.
                 *
                 * @param param The request param to be converted
                 * @param val The value of th =e request param
                 * @param req The Request object
                 * @returns {{skip: *}}
                 */
                'page': function (param, val, req) {
                    var limit = _.toInteger(req.query.limit);

                    if (!_.isInteger(limit)) {
                        limit = sails.config.blueprints.defaultLimit;
                    }

                    return {'skip': _.max([(_.toInteger(val) * limit) - limit, 0])};
                }
            };

        // default to all if invalid scope specified
        if (scopes.indexOf(scope) < 0) {
            scope = 'all';
        }

        opts = opts || {};

        // merge in user-provided configs with the defaults
        stripParams = _.concat(stripParams, opts.strip || []);
        keepParams = _.concat(keepParams, opts.keep || []);
        convertParams = _.merge(convertParams, opts.convert || []);

        // iterate over each of the scopes to process the params
        _.forEach(scopes, function (currScope) {
            if (scope === currScope || scope === 'all') {

                // strip the defined params from the request, optionally
                // keeping the ones marked as such
                _.forEach(stripParams, function (param) {
                    if (keepParams.indexOf(param) < 0) {

                        // eg: deletes `request.query._dc`
                        delete req[currScope][param];
                    }
                });

                // iterate the params to be converted to a new param
                _.forEach(convertParams, function (fn, param) {
                    var newParam;

                    // ensure the orig param exists before writing a new one
                    if (req[currScope][param]) {
                        newParam = fn(param, req[currScope][param], req);

                        // eg: deletes `request.query.page`
                        // adds `request.query.skip` with a calculated value
                        delete req[currScope][param];
                        _.merge(req[currScope], newParam);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

**ProjectController.js**

```
module.exports = {

    find: function (req, res) {
        // before: ?_dc=XXXXX&page=XX&limit=XX&start=XX
        // after: ?limit=XX&skip=XX
        util.sanitizeRequestParams(req, 'query', {strip: ['start']});

        // let Blueprints handle the `find` method like we never existed
        return sails.hooks.blueprints.middleware.find(req, res);
    }
};
```

There may be a far cleaner way to handle this such as lifecycle callbacks or hooks. I've not used Sails nor Node until now so it's all still green to me. Any feedback is appreciated.